# Terminal title bar size

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, gtk, titlebar

Is there a way to change Terminal title bar size? Mine looks huge:
[image: Mine looks huge]

Or maybe change the tabs locations to it, like in Chrome:
[image: like in chrome]

Comment: similar question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257163/reduce-title-bar-height-in-gnome-3-gtk-3

Comment: This looks like it is related to the custom theme and icon-set you are using. Try changing the theme and icon-set to see if it is related.